# How would you the length of a bordered region (that holds text) in HTML?

Tags: html, border, border-layout

I'm making a webpage using HTML and I am using borders around my text to give it a text box-type look. The problem I'm having is there are pictures and other elements I want to be beside the bordered text region. I currently have the picture beside the bordered text region as I wish however, the text continues running under the picture and I would like to fix this.

I tried searching on W3shools and a regular google search but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be is a z-index problem, or just where you are putting your text, in this example if i didn't miss understand shows how the text is always in a side of the image

html>>>

```
<div>
    <img src="./picture.png" alt="this is a picture">
    <div><p>some text</p></div>
</div>
```

css>>>

```
div{
    display: flex;
}
div>div{
    border: solid black 1px;
    height: fit-content;
}
```